# Qt, диагностика подключения QMYSQL

Tags: qt

Windows 7 x64, Qt 5.4. Тестовый проект:

```
#include <QtWidgets\QtWidgets>
#include <QtCore\QtCore>
#include <QtSql\QtSql>

#pragma comment(lib, "Qt5Widgets.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Qt5Core.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Qt5Sql.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    return app.exec();
}
```

При запуске:

> QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded QSqlDatabase: available
>   drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

При этом замена QMYSQL на QSQLITE приводит к тому что драйвер загружается и никаких сообщений об ошибках.

> C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2013\plugins\sqldrivers содержит qsqlite.dll,
>   qsqlited.dll, qsqlmysql.dll, qsqlmysqld.dll.

Вопрос: Как проблему пофиксить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько я помню, драйвер QSQLITE самодостаточен. А вот для работы QMYSQL необходимо наличие библиотеки libmySQL.dll.
Можно установить себе MySQL сервер, в папке lib MySQL сервера(в моем случае C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib) будет находится эта библиотека. Лучше всего положить её в каталог, который добавлен в системную переменную PATH, чтоб была доступна из любого места на компьютере. Ну или рядом с приложением, который используется QMYSQL драйвер.
И очень важно не забыть чтоб версия плагина и библиотека libMySQL.dll были одной разрядности.

Comment: Хм, то есть у драйвера есть еще и внешние зависимости? Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: qmysql.dll - это всего лишь обертка, которая позволяет написав один и тот же код, использовать его для sqlite, mysql и других баз, но сам функционал работы с базой - находится в libmysql.dll

Comment: Черт, логично...

Comment: Да, добавление libmysql.dll решило проблему с загрузкой, огромное спасибо! И ведь у qsqlmysql.dll в импортах действительно прописана эта DLL, и в итоге диагностика средствами Qt становится несколько затруднительной :-(

Answer (score 0):

Я сталкивался с такой проблемой совсем недавно. Решается она очень просто.

Чтобы проект заработал, нужно перетащить `mysqlclient.lib, libmysql.lib, libmysql.dll` в директорию со скомпиленным проектом. Например, проект лежит по адресу `D:\MyProject\`. Исходники лежат в `D:\MyProject\MyProject`. Скомпилили проект в `D:\MyProject\build-DAG_Visual-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug`. Внутрь директории `D:\MyProject\build-DAG_Visual-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug` и нужно положить указанные файлы. Такая ерундистика происходит, видимо, от того, что установочник QTMYSQL не прописывает пути к либам. Их можно, конечно, явно указать в *.pro. Другой способ -- это использовать `PATH`, как посоветовал @Александр .

Иногда начинает работать после того, как либы будут положены в `D:\MyProject\build-DAG_Visual-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug\Debug` или `D:\MyProject\build-DAG_Visual-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug\Realise`

Второй проблемой, которая может быть -- это отсутствие коннектора QTMYSQL для C++.

Мой проект собирался под QT 5.4, mingw x32

Указанные выше файлики у меня лежат здесь: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib`. Или здесь: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\vs10`

Comment: Ну с *.lib проблем не должно быть, иначе не собиралось бы...

Comment: Лично у меня заработало именно после добавления *.lib. Остальные же файлики помогали другим людям.

Answer (score -1):

sqlite, если нет файла-базы, создает файл нулевой длины. Можно попробовать вынести описание базы, как глобальное. В данном странноватом примере это может сработать

Comment: Я всего лишь загружаю драйвер БД, ни о каком подключении к базе речи не идет. И проблема возникает уже при загрузке драйвера.

Comment: И, собственно, вынос addDatabase() за main приводит к QSqlDatabase: an instance of QCoreApplication is required for loading driver plugins